# Join tables to display in progress and completed courses

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am making a university-like database and am wondering how to join my enrolment and coursesTaken tables in order to show all the courses taken and presently enrolled in by all the students. Here is part of the enrolment table:

```
+--------------+------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------+
| EnrollmentID | EnrolledOn | Student_StudentID | Class_ClassID | Status      |
+--------------+------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------+
|            1 | 08-23-2013 |                 1 |             1 | In Progress |
|            2 | 08-23-2013 |                 1 |             2 | In Progress |
|            3 | 08-23-2013 |                 1 |             3 | In Progress |
|            4 | 08-23-2013 |                 1 |             4 | In Progress |
|            5 | 08-23-2013 |                 1 |             5 | In Progress |
|            6 | 08-23-2013 |                 1 |             6 | In Progress |
|            7 | 08-23-2013 |                 1 |            22 | In Progress |
|            8 | 08-23-2013 |                 1 |            23 | In Progress |
|            9 | 08-23-2013 |                 1 |            36 | In Progress |
|           10 | 08-23-2013 |                 1 |            37 | In Progress |
|           11 | 08-23-2013 |                 2 |             7 | In Progress |
|           12 | 08-23-2013 |                 2 |             8 | In Progress |
|           13 | 08-23-2013 |                 2 |             9 | In Progress |
|           14 | 08-23-2013 |                 2 |            10 | In Progress |
|           15 | 08-23-2013 |                 2 |            11 | In Progress |
```

and here is part of the courses taken table:

```
+-------------------+-----------------+-----------+--------+-----------+
| Student_StudentID | Course_CourseID | Pass/Fail | Credit | Status    |
+-------------------+-----------------+-----------+--------+-----------+
|                 2 |               1 |         1 |      1 | Completed |
|                 2 |               2 |         1 |      1 | Completed |
|                 2 |               3 |         1 |      1 | Completed |
|                 2 |               4 |         1 |      1 | Completed |
|                 2 |               5 |         1 |      1 | Completed |
|                 2 |               6 |         1 |      1 | Completed |
|                 2 |              22 |         1 |      1 | Completed |
|                 2 |              23 |         1 |      1 | Completed |
|                 2 |              24 |         1 |      1 | Completed |
|                 2 |              25 |         1 |      1 | Completed |
|                 3 |               1 |         1 |      1 | Completed |
|                 3 |               2 |         1 |      1 | Completed |
|                 3 |               3 |         1 |      1 | Completed |
|                 3 |               4 |         1 |      1 | Completed |
|                 3 |               5 |         1 |      1 | Completed |
|                 3 |               6 |         1 |      1 | Completed |
```

As you can see some students such as student 1 do not have any courses taken since they are a first year and are only enrolled in courses. I would like a table that could put all of the studentID's from both tables in one table or view and list whether the status of their class is In Progress or if they have already completed the course.

Any advice on how I could join these 2 tables?

Comment: Dates should be stored using a date DATA TYPE. Further none of the students appear to be enrolled on any 'course' - although I see that they are attending 'classes'

Comment: Please show your best effort or at least post the desired outcome from the provided sample data

Comment: How `Class_ClassID` correlates to `Course_CourseID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a group by of both tables by student, then use a union query to add all the students id in one result.

Use this query as a subquery and make a left outer join to both tables and get the information related to the students you want.